# Chrome application run javascript on click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What am I doing wrong? I want to run a function when clicking "Show me some foo".

manifest.json browser_action

```
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "img/icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <div class="changes">

<span class="reset"><a href="#" title="Get some foo!" id="foo">Show me some foo</a>
</span>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
                       {file:"reset.js"});
});
```

reset.js

```
var el = document.getElementById('foo');
el.onclick = showFoo;


function showFoo() {
  alert('I am foo!');
  return false;
}
```

Full manifest.json file

```
{
  "name": "App name",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Desc.",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
],
  "js": ["js/myscript.js"],
  "exclude_matches":[
    "http://site.com/*"
]
}
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
"chrome_ex_oauth.html"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but I'll explain your code to you:

- user clicks a `browserAction`
- popup window is crated and scripts from `popup.html` are loaded
- `popup.js` loads and registers a listener `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener`
- user closes a popup window (by clicking anywhere outside it or on the `browserAction` again)
- `pupup.html` page is unloaded
- `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` listener is unregistered

As you can see `reset.js` is never loaded as it's never injected. What's more, you can't have a `popup.html` and `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` in the same extension ("This event will not fire if the browser action has a popup." [source](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked)).

You probably want to put `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` into the background page so that `reset.js` is injected to current page whenever `browserAction` is clicked. And, as I mentioned above, for `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` to fire, you need to get rid of `"default_popup": "popup.html"` from manifest.

If you wanted to inject a script to `popup.html` - it doesn't make much sense. You have full control over `popup.html` and you can simply put `reset.js` in the `<head>`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the explaining this to me. I have this fiddle which shows a bit better what I m trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/cPAN5/. To be brief, I want to change a few words on a page, then display what was changed in popup.html and have a button which will undo the changes.

Comment: That's great, but what is the question here? :) My approach to such an extension would probably go like this: create a `popup.html` that, when opened, executes a script at current page (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)  that does word changing and returns relevant results. Then, in the callback, read the results and show them. For the undo button, basically do the same - execute a script that undoes changes on current page.

Comment: The script will run when the page loads and then in popup.html I just want to display the results. That's where it gets a little confusing. I wasn't using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, I was just loading the script. i just put this in the head of background.html but the page color doesn't change. `<script>
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"document.body.style.backgroundColor='red'"});
</script>`

Comment: If you put `chrome.tabs.executeScript(` in the head of `background.html` it will run only once - when extension will be activated. If you want this to run for each tab when it loads you should probably put `chrome.tabs.executeScript(` inside the callback from http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated .